# Reverse geocoding with progress apply

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have a data frame with a column of latitude coordinates and a column of longitude coordinates and I am trying to call the progress_apply function with both of these columns as arguments because I have a large data set and need to use the RateLimiter  wrapper. My problem is that progress_apply is having a hard time recognizing tuples in a dataframe. Here is my code:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="user")
reverse = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=0.1, max_retries=10)

data = pd.read_excel('file_path')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Column3','Column4','Column21','Column22','Column23'])
df.columns = ['status', 'class', 'year', 'latitude', 'longitude']
df['points'] = [(tuple['latitude'], tuple['longitude']) for i, tuple in df.iterrows()]

tqdm.pandas()
df['country'] = df['points'].progress_apply(lambda x: reverse(x).raw['address']['country'])
```

The program raises "ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point" but when I check to see what type x is using type(x), the program recognizes it as tuple.

Any help is appreciated. Also if you know a better way to get the country information from the latitude and longitude that would also work.

Comment: I've just tried the code you provided and it worked for me. Although I have created a little DataFrame by hand (because the contents of `file_path` are unclear). Could you please try to also create a DataFrame by hand to ensure that the error is not caused by your source file? Otherwise, if that works, try to find the difference between the two.

Comment: For example: `df = pd.DataFrame({"latitude": [80.3, 60.3], "longitude": [34.5, 22.3]})`. In the end I got `list(df['country']) == ['Norge', 'Suomi']`.